# DomPDF: Distorted Image when rendered in a production server

Tags: php, image, dompdf

I have a PHP file which generates pdf document via DomPDF that has a logo on it. If generated on localhost machine, the logo is displayed properly...

[image]

BUT if the file is executed from an online server (Godaddy.com),  the image is distorted as shown below...

[image]

The HTML code is as follows...

```
<img src="img/crempco_logo.png" style="height: 50px; float: right;">
```

In a nutshell:

• The logo image is displayed properly in localhost.

• But, the logo image is distorted in a production server.

• The logo image is in .png format.

So, anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried changing the server, see here this issue also had server issues, changed the server problem was solved https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1497

Comment: i've looked around in the suggested solutions from the link you provided but nothing seemed to work for me except for the changing of server as i currently have no other production server...

Comment: how about using a jpg instead of png as I have also heard another issue in which png was creating some issues, or maybe svg if you have used svg with dompdf

Comment: oh i haven't tried that yet, i'll give it a go and see if it works